# display the last record value of has_many relation in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I Have a project model which has_many builds
How can I display In my haml file the status of the last build for each project

```
%table
  - @projects.each do |project|
    %tr
      %td #{project.name}
      %td #{project.created_at}
      %td #{project.builds.last.status} //this line is wrong
      %td #{project.builds.last.size}
```

I am using ruby version: 2.0.0p247

The error is: "undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Why that line is wrong? Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: it should be #{project.builds.status} unless if you have last as a column in your build table

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work and it seems reasonable as there are many builds for one project, so asking for the status must be specify on a specific record of builds (I guess...)

Comment: What's the error message? Also it seems pretty weird you're iterating over `@project` (singular) and it's in fact a collection of projects.

Comment: Also you could just put `%td= project.builds.last.status` instead of  `%td #{project.builds.last.status}`

Comment: wrong typo, I iterates over projects which have item project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems one particular project simply doesn't have any builds. You get `nil` when you call `last` on an empty collection and calling `status` will give you the error. The solution is to just check the project's `builds` collection before working with its elements (`unless project.builds.empty?`).